# tab space on a JLabel not showing - weird - Java

Tags: java, string, swing, jlabel

I'm trying to update a JLabel with new text and I need this text to have tabed space.

This is my code:

```
public void setNewLabelTxt(String text)
{
    nameLabel.setText(text + "\t");
}
```

The label is updated but there is no tab space at the end and I can't figure why. As far as I know `\t` is the way to add tab space.

Comment: As far as I remember `JLabel` does not render tab characters properly. If you're attempting to use the tab to give yourself some additional room on the right side after the label, consider checking out the [`BoxLayout`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/box.html) class.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`JLabel` doesn't render `\t` in any special way (ie, it doesn't convert the `\t` to spaces before rendering it).

Instead, you should use something like

```
text = text.replaceAll("\t", "    ");
```

Before applying it to the label.